# Is there a way to restrict CRUD operations on Notes/Domino data using an alternative application?

Tags: excel, vba, dll, com, lotus-notes

We have a (super)user who has been using VBA in an Excel spreadsheet to create and manipulate documents in a Domino database application.
The user has 'Editor' access to the application, and should normally be able to create/edit the document contents.
They have been, however, creating documents using VBA. That logic doesn't consider such important document fields as Readers, Authors, etc. .

**We would like to restrict access to all Domino data so that it can only be created/modified using an IBM Notes client.**

I have tried looking through the ECL, but that only restricts what 'others' do.
Since he has his Notes client available, the external logic is using his normal Notes credentials.

I have tried setting a hidden field with the Notes client and looking for that in the QuerySave event of the form design.
Unfortunately, the external code pays no attention to the form events and the save is executed despite the missing field.

Similarly, the Database Script has no bearing on the execution of external logic. 
I was going to inspect the client version upon database open and restrict activity based on a variance in the version (I was hoping!).

I have de-selected the 'Don't prompt for a password...' option in the user security preferences, but that has no effect at all (suspected as much!).

The ONLY thing I have been able to suggest is to hide the database design... That's really only designed to thwart a user's efforts to understand the underlying design.
It won't prevent them from creating hundreds of thousands of documents with a fictitious form and throwing the app into disarray.

I'm hoping that there is a solution out there that I'm missing.

The user has been instructed not to undertake such activity in the future.
We were lucky that there really wasn't any malicious intent - "Just trying to be more efficient" we're told.
The effects of the activity have been remedied, and the user has been warned.

**What I want to know is...  how can I prevent this from ever happening again?**

The circumstances are rare I know, but I would've thought there'd be a means of restricting the platforms used to manage Notes/Domino data.
Is there a way to ensure no external applications are able to access, create or modify Notes database documents?

I am currently focussing on access to Notes via COM.
I thought that, if I unregistered 'nlsxbe.dll' from the registry, that would prevent such activity - It has not.
I also tried removing the .TLB files from the Notes executable folder - removal of 'notes32.tlb' and 'domobj.tlb' have no effect at all. Removal of 'ltsci3.tlb' screws everything up (as expected!).

I'm really having no luck at all - Any/all suggestions would be most appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any way to detect that a connection has been made by standalone code instead of by the Notes client, but you do have two paths available to you:

- A Domino server add-in that prevents documents from being saved in that particular database if certain criteria aren't met.
- An agent that is triggered to run shortly [after documents are saved or modified](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSVRGU_8.5.3/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_TRIGGERING_AN_AGENT_ON_AN_EVENT_STEPS.html) in that particular database. The agent code can delete (or modify, if you prefer) the documents that don't conform to the required criteria.

The server add-in route would normally require coding in C, but thanks to the Open NTF Trigger Happy project, the hard part is done for you, and the rest can be filled in with either LotusScript or Java agent code that is "triggered" by the pre-written C code. You will need to have some basic knowledge of how the [Notes Extension Manager interface](http://www-12.lotus.com/ldd/doc/domino_notes/9.0/api90ug.nsf/85255d56004d2bfd85255b1800631684/06fd173414dcdad9852560eb0077ca42?OpenDocument) works, but once you get past that and write your agent code to enforce your data consistency/integrity requirements, the only real hurdle is your willingness to host open source code on your server.

Comment: Thanks Richard!  

Tried the agent route... solution consisted of three components...  

- Hide database design  
- Add hidden, computed 'flag' field to Notes form design  
- Look for that field and remove documents where it's missing  

Unfortunately, the agent is basically a scheduled agent and doesn't prevent document creation. The documents are, however, effectively removed.  

That may be all that's required, because that will identify 'dirty data' and let us know who is executing the logic.  

Intrigued by the add-in tho, and will certainly explore that.  

Cheers!

Comment: You can set the agent so it is triggered when documents are created or modified, but even then there will often be a delay of a few minutes before it's run, so it's not that much different than running it as scheduled.  I also should have mentioned that ExtraComm's product SecurTrak for Notes can probably detect documents like this, and maybe take action on them. It's been a long time since I checked into its features, though, and it sounds like you've got the situation in hand now anyhow.

Answer (score 0):

There may be two other possibilities, but I can't say if either will solve or deal with the issue...

1. In the ECL you can disable 'COM' access for the user (also known as OLE or ActiveX) automation since VBA access is usually via COM. This has stopped Notes using external COM access for me, but I don't know if also prevents VBA using Notes. Additional steps may be needed to enforce the ECL and apply to the specific users.
2. There is an (old) notes.ini 'DisableExternalApps' (or something similar) that disables some external access. This can affect many things (DDE/Prompts/@dblookups) but again I don't know if this will disable VBA/COM and its not user specific, but server wide.

I would have thought that removing the nlsxbe.dll or restricting access to execute it might work, but the ECL may be the best bet.

Alternatively, rather than add hidden flags to your design (and the documents), and then delete the offending documents, your agent could apply the correct author/reader fields to the documents instead.

Very tricky. Did you find a better solution?